# Can MEF ImportMany be static?

Tags: c#, mef

When I say this it works fine.

```
    [ImportMany]
    public IEnumerable<IAPI> Apis;
```

But if I changed it to

```
    [ImportMany]
    public static IEnumerable<IAPI> Apis;
```

It doesn't work - meaning that the `IEnumerable` doesn't contain anything. I see no reason why this should be and it is `probably` a bug in my code, but before I go crazy looking for it, I want to check that `ImportMany` in fact **cannot** be `static`?

Comment: See edited post.

Comment: Read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8786214/656243) yet?

Comment: Thanks that is helpful.