# MEF share instance between modules

Tags: c#, mef, prism-4

I'm using PRISM/MEF for my C# application. I want to do the following, I'm really new to PRISM and maybe I'm doing something completely wrong or got something wrong but it does not work like showed below.

I created two modules, where in Module1 I created an instance of a class. I want to share this instance with the other Module2.

Something like this:

Module1 (ViewModel):

```
[Export("ME")]
private Person me = new Person();
//within some function...
me.Name = "Jasmin";
```

Module2 (ViewModel):

```
[Import("ME")]
private Lazy<Person> me;
//within some function
Console.Writeline(me.Name); //here I want to get "Jasmin"
```

Shared Model Class:

```
public class Details
{
   public string Name;
}
public class Person
{
   public Name first = new Name();
}
```

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010437/c-sharp-singleton-pattern-and-mef. Do you use different MEF containers throughout your object hierarchy?

Comment: No there is just one from the bootstrapper. I had a look at this link before but still I do not see the answer to make it work. I would be thankful if someone could modify my code to make it work. I guess it is not complicated after all?

Comment: @user2799180 Do you get an error or something? By the way me.Name should be me.Value.Name.

Comment: I do not know what happened but it works now. Exactly as it should. Maybe it all it needed was a rebuild of the entire solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It exactly works like shown in my question. I just had to rebuild the entire solution.

To access the object later on, instead of:

```
Console.Writeline(me.Name); //here I want to get "Jasmin"
```

One has to use:

```
Console.Writeline(me.Value.Name); //here I want to get "Jasmin"
```

Thanks for your help.