# How to create a fully lazy singleton for generics

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, singleton

I have the following code implementation of my generic singleton provider:

```
public sealed class Singleton<T> where T : class, new()
{
     Singleton()
     {
     }

     public static T Instance
     {
          get { return SingletonCreator.instance; }
     }

     class SingletonCreator
     {
          static SingletonCreator()
          {
          }

          internal static readonly T instance = new T();
     }
}
```

This sample was taken from 2 articles and I merged the code to get me what I wanted:

http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/singleton.html and
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11111/Generic-Singleton-Provider.

This is how I tried to use the code above:

```
public class MyClass
{
     public static IMyInterface Initialize()
     {
          if (Singleton<IMyInterface>.Instance == null  // Error 1
          {
               Singleton<IMyInterface>.Instance = CreateEngineInstance();  // Error 2
               Singleton<IMyInterface>.Instance.Initialize();
          }

          return Singleton<IMyInterface>.Instance;
     }
}
```

And the interface:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
}
```

The error at `Error 1` is:

```
'MyProject.IMyInterace' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'MyProject.Singleton<T>'
```

The error at `Error 2` is:

```
Property or indexer 'MyProject.Singleton<MyProject.IMyInterface>.Instance' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
```

How can I fix this so that it is in line with the 2 articles mentioned above?  Any other ideas or suggestions are appreciated.

Does my implementation break the Singleton pattern?

Comment: singleton is dead; [lifetime/scoping should be handled by dependency injection containers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484619/does-mef-lend-any-value-to-the-singleton-pattern/4484889#4484889) these days.

Comment: Absolutely. It is the singleton's responsability to create and control the lifecycle of a single object, but you're trying to assign a value to the instance property of the singleton class OUTSIDE of that class. What you're really trying to do from what I see is dependency injection and interface-based programming. Singleton is only useful when you're trying to use sparce ressources (database connection for example), and should be used with care (even avoided)

Comment: I am trying to create an engine for my web mvc app, it handles everything that I need, dependency injection, and I only want 1 instances of this instance to exist.

Comment: Then KISS. Keep It Stupid Simple. Write a regular singleton in your app engine class, and don't bother with generics. It's overkill.

Comment: @T.Fabre: I guess you make sense.  And if I were to need another singleton instance of another different obkect in my app?

Comment: Do the same thing. If you get so many singleton's that you need a generic singleton provider, you **really** **really** ought to review your design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you've given a class constraint on your singleton class, along with the new() constraint.

When writing

```
Singleton<IMyInterface>
```

you're using an interface type as T, which violates the type constraint you defined.

For error 2,

```
Singleton<IMyInterface>.Instance = CreateEngineInstance();
```

you're trying to assign a value to a read-only property. So you need to define a setter on your Instance property for that line to work.

**Update**

Something along these lines should do it for you :

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
     private static Hashtable bindings = new Hashtable();
     private static Hashtable instances = new Hashtable();

     private static void checkType(Type requested, Type bound)
     {
        if (requested.IsValueType)
            throw new Exception("Cannot bind a value type to a reference type");

        // also check type inheritance and other things...
     }

     private static void checkBinding(Type requested)
     {
        if (!(bindings.ContainsKey(requested)))
            throw new Exception(String.Format("Type {0} was not bound !", requested.FullName));
     }

     public static void Bind<T, U>() where U : class, new() 
     {
        checkType(typeof(T), typeof(U));
        bindings[typeof(T)] = typeof(U);
     }

     public static T GetInstance<T>() 
     {
        Type requested = typeof(T);
        Type bound = (Type) bindings[requested];

        checkBinding(requested);

        if (!instances.ContainsKey(requested)) {
            // We know that type "bound" was set with a new() class constraint
            instances[requested] = (T) Activator.CreateInstance(bound);
        }

        return (T) instances[requested];
     }
}
```

You could then write :

```
 Singleton.Bind<IMyInterface, MyClass>();
 IMyInterface instance = Singleton.GetInstance<IMyInterface>();
```

If you want to go further, you could also specify the lifecycle of the objects created by this provider, so that you could use singletons, or have the provider return a new object for each call, and so on.

You should also take a look at the Dependency Injection pattern, which seems close to what you want achieve, and also look at existing DI frameworks (NInject, Nhibernate) that already do this and much more.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you have an issue there. You generic is suppose to take class, not interface.

```
internal static readonly T instance = new T();
```

Your code suppose to create an instance of that class, you could not instantiate interface type.

So, if you need some type to act as singletone, you should write:

```
Singleton<MyInterface>.Instance
```

where

```
public class MyInterface : IMyInterface { }
```

Then you don't need to have any 'if' in you code, since it Singleton responsibility to instantite an object and keep it as only one instance.

Not related to question: currently Singletone's are considered by many developers as 'code-smell', so in general you have to avoid them. Try to think you application without Singletone at all.

Comment: I have an engine that I want to use throughout my mvc app.  It handles stuff like dependency injection, getting the current user, etc.  This is why I want a single of the engine.

Comment: Taking into account you comment, I would say - you are doing something really wrong in your MVC application. If you have IoC container in app, many of them have InSingletoneScope() strategy of object creation. You don't need to create your own.